# Error including serialport in project.pro file in QT

Tags: qt, serial-port

I have downloaded the latest version of QT and I am including the serialport in .pro file but it says

```
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: serialport
```

And because of this, I am not able to include the QSerialPort in my project. I don't know why its not available as I am using the latest version of QT. Here is the screenshot of the QT about menu:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me something. Thanks.!

[image]

Comment: Please show your line in the .pro file.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I have added a screenshot

Comment: I think you should use 'widgets serialport'.
as in: greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets\
                                        widgets serialport\